# How to get posts from WordPress in iOS application?

Tags: ios, wordpress, api

I want to write an app for iOS which will get posts from WordPress site. Where shoul I take API's and how to use them?

Answer (score 1):

You could use the Wordpress built-in RSS Feed. You can have a closer look in the documentation [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Feeds). Then you could use [KissXML](https://github.com/robbiehanson/KissXML) or [any other XML Parser](http://www.raywenderlich.com/553/how-to-chose-the-best-xml-parser-for-your-iphone-project) and get the results into your app.

Comment: There is a comment parameter in each item which gives you the URL to the comments feed. The comments feed is also an RSS-Feed

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by btype you can use the build in RSS feed. [WordPressSyncer](https://github.com/NextfazeSD/WordPressSyncer) is a library that will take the feed and save it into core data.

Another option could be to use a wordpress plugin such as [WPoniOS](https://github.com/vincentsaluzzo/WPoniOS---REST-API) which provides a REST API for the blog.